# How to trigger an event when bootstrap modal closes

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Suppose I have a modal for example 
[image]

I want to trigger an event when this modal is closed. THe model get closed when we click on the close button or anywhere outside the close button

```
    <a href='#part-3' data-toggle='modal' id='sss' style='float:right; color:black;' >view</a></center>

 //code for modal

  <div class="modal modal-wide fade" id="part-3" >
<div class="modal-dialog" style="min-width:60%">
  <div class="modal-content" >
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" >&times;</button>

    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="show">
           //the html code of form which is popped up
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I can easily create an jquery event when closing the modal through close button by giving it an id but how to trigger/ what should be name of that trigger when user click anywhere outside the modal..

Comment: Are you using a framework like Bootstrap?

Comment: AFAIK HTML5 has no built-in modal functionality.

Comment: yes i am using bootstrap framework

Comment: Have you tried reading the documentation?

Answer (score 11):

In bootstrap, a javascript event already fires when a modal is closed/hidden:

```
$('#myModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function (e) {
  // do something...
})
```

See the relevant [documentation here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) for more events.